How to stop expanding objects into JSON in spring rest controller's response?
I have been writing an endpoint which responds an user information. User class has id, name, and posts. posts is list of Post class, which includes User so that when I requested the endpoints, the following response returned.
{"id":1,"name":"foo","posts":[{"id":1,"name":"diary","createdAt":null,"user":{"id":1,"name":"foo","posts":...

What I excepted:
{"id": 1, "name": "foo", "posts":[{"id": 1, "name": "diarty", "createdAt": null, "userId": 1}]}

To fix the behaviour, how should I rewrites program?
User.java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    public List<Post> posts;
}

Post.java
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public Date createdAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user")
    public User user;
}

The endpoint:
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public User getUserInfo(@PathVariable Long id) {
  Optional<User> res = userRepo.findById(id);
  if (res.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no user " + id + " found");
  } else {
    return res.get();
  }
}


You can put @JsonIgnore on the user inside the post if you really want to do this, but serializing an ORM entity is a bad practice overall. Define a data class like UserPostView or just List which contains fields in the form and shape you want to see them on the client side

Use of DTOs will give us control over the expected response.
Create PostDTO
public class PostDTO {
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public Date createdAt;
    public Long userId;

    public PostDTO(Post post) {
        this.id = post.id;
        this.name = post.name;
        this.createdAt = post.createdAt;
        this.userId = post.user.id;
    }
}

Create UserDTO
public class UserDTO {
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public List<PostDTO> posts;

    public UserDTO(User user) {
        this.id = user.id;
        this.name = user.name;
        this.posts = user.posts.stream()
                               .map(PostDTO::new)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

Make the required changes in the controller,
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public UserDTO getUserInfo(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Optional<User> res = userRepo.findById(id);
    if (res.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No user " + id + " found");
    } else {
        return new UserDTO(res.get());
    }
}

The above code changes result in the expected JSON response.
Additionally, we can use modelmapper, which simplifies the mapping between entities and DTOs.
